# Chart.js not responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this gem https://github.com/jhudson8/react-chartjs to create charts.

I installed the module, and imported a part of it like this:

```
var LineChart = require('react-chartjs').Line;
```

Then, I tried creating a simple line chart after looking at the documentation http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-structure:

```
<LineChart data={chartData} options={{bezierCurve: false}} width="250" height="250"/>
```

However, in the browser I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)[chartType] is not a function
```

and also

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
```

My entire component is this:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import FlipCard from 'react-flipcard';
var LineChart = require('react-chartjs').Line;

var SampleDisplay = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {flipped: false};
  },

  mouseOut: function() {
    console.log("Mouse out!!!");
    this.setState({flipped: false});
  },

  mouseOver: function() {
    console.log("Mouse over!!!");
    this.setState({flipped: true});
  },

  render: function() {

    const chartData = {
      labels: ["Happiness", "Safety", "Weather"],
      datasets: [
          {
              label: "My First dataset",
              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
              highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
              highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              data: [65, 59, 80]
          }
      ]
    };

    const itemStyle = {
      display: 'block',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundImage: `url('${this.props.item.url}')`
    };

    const backGroundStyle = {
      backgroundImage: `url('${this.props.item.url}')`
    };

    return (<div className="gridItem" onMouseEnter={this.mouseOver} onMouseLeave={this.mouseOut}>
              {this.state.flipped
                ?
                <LineChart data={chartData} options={{}} width="250" height="250"/>
                :
                <div style={itemStyle}>

                </div>
              }
          </div>);
  }
});

module.exports = SampleDisplay;
```

Comment: Can you post the entire React component class?

Comment: nice, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install the Chart.js NPM package as outlined in the React-Chartjs documentation.

> You must also include chart.js and React as dependencies.

```
npm install chart.js@1.0.2 --save
```

If you already have chart.js installed, it is likey at v2.0 which is not yet stable and creates the error. Uninstall v2 and reinstall using the line above.

Comment: I did that. I still get the same issues though.

Comment: Fixed the problem!